# Concrete pour against green board

Tags: drywall, concrete, floor, moisture

I'm having a new concrete floor poured in. its going to be 4 inches.

The drywall that will be in contact with the cement is green board(moisture resistant).

Will that be ok? or should I cut the bottom 6 inches of drywall and put pressure treated boards?

Comment: Images would help...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a new 4 inches of floor on a ground level structure...

No this is definitely not ok.

Greenboard is mold resistant.  It is, however, still just gypsum with paper over it.

Neither is using pressure treated wood as a barrier.

Why?

Concrete wicks water.  Any water near the area will be distributed to be brought into direct contact with the gypsum or wood.  Gypsum and paper, when left exposed to moisture, falls apart.  Wood, even pressure treated, will rot eventually.

This is why sill plates, which sit on top of foundation walls that can be several feet above ground, are protected by moisture barriers.

You need to put a waterproof (PROOF, not resistant) substance between the new concrete and existing walls, OR lift the walls up (not likely feasible).

Comment: I agree about the drywall, but in my part of the world it's routine to use PT lumber directly on concrete. We don't have houses rotting away. After 20 years or more they're fine.

Comment: It's also code in NA to use a moisture barrier (such as poly, or other impermeable materials) between the sill plate and the concrete.

Comment: @isherwood just because it is done that way, doesn't make it the right way to do it.

Comment: @Chris What is "NA", and what source are you citing? I've been out of the business for a handful of years and may have missed some recent changes.

Comment: @Isherwood NA as in North America (well, US, and Canada) PT is also code, but as [this](http://www.bcbec.com/docs/2%20-%20BCIT%20_%20Herman%20Kwok.pdf) would suggest, technically, PT is worse than untreated directly on concrete (in terms of absorption, not mold growth, it's unquestionably better than untreated).

Comment: You may be able to get away with using PT directly on concrete if you live in more arid regions.  However, it's hardly expensive or hard to add a moisture barrier, and even in arid regions you can have areas prone to accumulate moisture, so why take the chance?  Why build something to last 20 years when a few pennies more can make it last 100?